# Node Js Joi validation is not working for me

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I am using Joi to validate the data received from an excel file and even if I am not defined anything in schema it gives the attached errors: "name" is not allowed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQupf.png)

Here is my code:

```
const schemaJoi = {};
    
const validation = Joi.object(schemaJoi).validate(candidates);
console.log(validation.error.details[0].message);
```

When the data is perfect it still doesn't allow that data to be passed.

Kindly help.

Comment: In joi you should put the things that are supposed to be validated and passed to the final object, if you pass an empty object, nothing is going to be valid

Comment: Thanks for your reply sebastian, I put an empty schema object just for example, when i put an empty schema object it still displays errors which are in the payload and those are valid, my question is simple why it is still displaying the errors when the schema is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you want joi to skip validation of unknown attributes, add the following to your validate call:

```
options={allowUnknown:true}
```

For example:

```
const joi = require('joi');

const schema = {};

const validation = joi.object(schema).validate(
  payload={a:1, b:2},
  options={allowUnknown:true}
);

if (validation.error) {
  console.log(validation.error.details[0].message);
}
```